# Windows Remote User Managment

Tags: windows-7, users

I have a server PC and several client PCs, each running Windows 7 Home.

I would like to create a user on the server PC and have that user then available on all client PCs.  User1 should be able to login to any PC with his credentials.

Also, files on the server PC need to be selectively shared with users on the client PC.  For example,  User1 should have access to a directory that User2 may not.

What is the best way to manage user accounts across multiple PCs like this?  Do I need to use a workgroup or domain instead of the HomeGroup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, you'll need to use Active Directory. Unfortunately the home version of Windows doesn't support joining an AD domain.

Additionally, you'll need a server version of windows to host AD. You mention having a "server", but don't specify what OS it's running.

Comment: Yeah, I'm hosed.  The "server" is just a beefed up PC that is used as a filestore and such.  It's just running Win7 Pro which apparently can't create a domain either... looks like I need to get some variant of Windows Server, blach.