# Windows file sharing permissions with remote users

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Remote User Managment](https://serverfault.com/questions/370729/windows-remote-user-managment)

I have files on one Win7 Pro system that need to get shared with specific users of another Win7 Pro system.  For example, PC2/User1 should have access but PC2/User2 should not have access.

When I attempt to adjust the "Share With" on the host PC, I cannot explicitly add remote users to the ACL because the host system does not know the remote system's users...

Any suggestions for working around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a feature of a domain (centralized authentication).

if you want to simulate this with the local SAM, all users acccounts that you're concerned with must mirror each other on all Windows 7 boxes (username / password).  Then simply lock down the local users in the way you've requested.

BTW, share permission arn't the best way to lock stuff down.  Go with NTFS...